# Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component - error displayed when tryingto use useNavigation() to redirect

Tags: typescript, react-native, hook

I am new to React native and I try to redirect after Facebook login bu I get the `Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component` . I Here is my code. Please give me some help with the issue. The login works until I try to use useNavigation().

```
export default function LoginScreen({ path }: { path: string }) {
  return (
      <Container style={styles.container} >
        <FormControl>
          <Button style={styles.loginButton} onPress={FacebookLogin}>
            <Text style={styles.textButton}>Login with Facebook</Text>
          </Button>
        </FormControl>
      </Container>
  );
}

async function FacebookLogin(){
  try {
    await Facebook.initializeAsync({
      appId: '...',
    });
    const data = await Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync({
      permissions: ['public_profile'],
    });
    if (data.type === 'success') {
      const response = await fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=${(data.token)}`);
      //type authScreenProp = StackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList, 'Dashboard'>;
      // const navigation = useNavigation<authScreenProp>();
      //rconsole.log(await response.json());
      Alert.alert('Logged in!', `Hi ${(await response.json()).name}!`);
      const navigation = useNavigation();
      navigation.navigate('Dashboard');
    } else {
      // type === 'cancel'
    }
  } catch ({ message }) {
    alert(`Facebook Login Error: ${message}`);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, you cannot call a hook outside of a function component, so you need to move `const navigation = useNavigation();` to `LoginScreen` and pass it to the handler as a parameter: `onPress={()=>FacebookLogin(navigation )}`